# extract date from html document

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a pretty large html file.
I need to scrape this html file and extract certain information

```
soup.findAll('table',{"summary" : "This table displays snapshot information"})

[<table border="1" summary="This table displays snapshot information" width="500">
 <tbody><tr><th class="awrnobg" scope="col"></th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Id</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Time</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Sessions</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Cursors/Session</th></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Begin Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">98810</td><td align="center" class="awrnc">29-Jun-15 08:00:02</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">700</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">    129.6</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">End Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrc">98864</td><td align="center" class="awrc">29-Jun-15 17:00:23</td><td align="right" class="awrc">703</td><td align="right" class="awrc">    129.1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Elapsed:</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrnc">             540.35 (mins)</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td class="awrnc"> </td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">DB Time:</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrc">           2,963.17 (mins)</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td class="awrc"> </td></tr>
 </tbody></table>]
```

Using beautiful soup i managed to get a list.
But i need to extract the date 29-Jun-15 08:00:02 any ideas 
I can manipulate the list items individually but that looks ugly to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just search for the `td` using its `class`. It should return a list and you can proceed from there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

html = """<table border="1" summary="This table displays snapshot information" width="500">
 <tbody><tr><th class="awrnobg" scope="col"></th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Id</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Time</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Sessions</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Cursors/Session</th></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Begin Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">98810</td><td align="center" class="awrnc">29-Jun-15 08:00:02</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">700</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">    129.6</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">End Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrc">98864</td><td align="center" class="awrc">29-Jun-15 17:00:23</td><td align="right" class="awrc">703</td><td align="right" class="awrc">    129.1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Elapsed:</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrnc">             540.35 (mins)</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td class="awrnc"> </td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">DB Time:</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrc">           2,963.17 (mins)</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td class="awrc"> </td></tr>
 </tbody></table>"""

soup = bsoup(html)
print soup.find_all('td', class_='awrnc')[2].get_text()
# 29-Jun-15 08:00:02
```

EDIT:

Taking into account your original code that returns a list of tables, just use normal list indexing/slicing to get what the table you want. See my following example. I changed the above HTML to have three `table`s that have the same `summary` attribute. My code will return all three, so I'll select the first one. Then, I'll look for all the `td`s that match my defined `class`. I'll then choose the third one using `[2]`. Then, I'll use `get_text()` to get the value inside the target `td` element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

html = """<html><body><table border="1" summary="This table displays snapshot information" width="500">
 <tbody><tr><th class="awrnobg" scope="col"></th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Id</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Time</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Sessions</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Cursors/Session</th></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Begin Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">98810</td><td align="center" class="awrnc">29-Jun-15 08:00:02</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">700</td><td align="right" class="awrnc">    129.6</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">End Snap:</td><td align="right" class="awrc">98864</td><td align="center" class="awrc">29-Jun-15 17:00:23</td><td align="right" class="awrc">703</td><td align="right" class="awrc">    129.1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrnc" scope="row">Elapsed:</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrnc">             540.35 (mins)</td><td class="awrnc"> </td><td class="awrnc"> </td></tr>
 <tr><td class="awrc" scope="row">DB Time:</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td align="center" class="awrc">           2,963.17 (mins)</td><td class="awrc"> </td><td class="awrc"> </td></tr>
 </tbody></table><table summary="This table displays snapshot information"></table><table summary="This table displays snapshot information"></table><body><html>"""

soup = bsoup(html)

list_of_tables = soup.find_all("table", {"summary":"This table displays snapshot information"}) # This will return 3 tables based on the above HTML.
target_table = list_of_tables[0] # Target the first one.

list_of_tds = target_table.find_all('td', class_='awrnc')
target_td = list_of_tds[2]
target_value = target_td.get_text()
print target_value
# 29-Jun-15 08:00:02
```

TL;DR: Just use `[0]` on your list. Seems like it's the only table you find anyway. After that, you can search inside it again, as it becomes a valid `BeautifulSoup` HTML string.

Comment: My soup is part of large html document.So i should be combining the find condition you gave me with mine i.e soup.findAll('table',{"summary" : "This table displays snapshot information"}) no ?But when i use my condition html is converted to a list

Comment: That's because `find_all` or `findAll` returns a list. Amending my answer so that you can understand it better.